# If two column has Yes then new column should be Yes in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have below table:

| Name | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | N | Y |
| Z | N | Y | N |

I want to create new column Res which should be Y if any two columns out of A B C is Y else should be N

| Name | A | B | C | Res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | N | Y | Y |
| Z | N | Y | N | N |

PS: I have more than three column to check on

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT Name, A, B, C, 
    CASE 
        WHEN 'Y' IN (A,B) OR 'Y' IN (A,C) OR 'Y' IN (B,C) THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS Res
FROM [table_name];
```

If you have many columns and can use `UNPIVOT` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT u.Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, A, B, C
    FROM your_table_name
) DS
UNPIVOT 
(
    Res FOR Col IN (A, B, C)
) UNPVT
WHERE UNPVT.Res = 'Y'
GROUP BY UNPVT.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.Col) >= 2;
```

Comment: ``` WHEN 'Y' IN (A,B)``` logic populates Res as Y even when A is N,  B is Y and C is N. @gotqn Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, case when A = "Y" AND B = "Y" then "Y"
               when B = "Y" AND C = "Y" then "Y"
               when A = "Y" AND C = "Y" then "Y"
               else "N"
               end as Res
FROM your_table
```